# Django: filtering queryset by 'field__isnull=True' or 'field=None'?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, isnull

I have to filter a queryset by a dynamic value (which can be None): may I simply write:

```
filtered_queryset = queryset.filter(field=value)
```

or shall I check for None:

```
if value is None:
    filtered_queryset = queryset.filter(field__isnull=True)
else:
    filtered_queryset = queryset.filter(field=value)
```

Does the behaviour depend on the particular DBMS?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The ORM will handle `None` (cast it to NULL) for you and return a `QuerySet` object, so unless you need to catch `None` input the first example is fine.

```
>>> User.objects.filter(username=None)
[]
>>> type(_)
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
>>> str(User.objects.filter(username=None).query)
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username" IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 I was unaware it handled `None` like that, very useful to know.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.7 and both cases generate the same query:

    In [19]: str(User.objects.filter(username__isnull=True).query) == str(User.objects.filter(username=None).query)
    Out[19]: True

So, I suppose you can use either.

Comment: Do note that `None` is ***not*** handled correctly if you use the `__in` lookup. For example, `filter(something__in=[None, 1])` does not work as expected. See e.g. [Django ticket 20024](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20024) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60392280).

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the second solution which is handled better

`Update`

```py
if value is None:
    filtered_queryset = queryset.filter(field__isnull=True)
    # Do some proessing with  filtered_queryset object with None values
else:
    filtered_queryset = queryset.filter(field=value)
    # Do some proessing with  filtered_queryset object with not NULL values
```

Query set can handle Null values..Based on this  `User.objects.filter(username=None)`  this would fetch only values where username=NULL

Comment: The only reason which suggested your second condition was if u wanted to handle None conditions and do some processing on it then u could have used the second solution.Please see the updated answer..

Comment: Thanks. One last question: when you say "this would fetch only values where username=NULL", you mean that Django would translate into "username IS NULL" in case it is required by the DB backend?

Comment: For example `1)queryset = MyModel.objects.all()` `2)print queryset.query` `3)SELECT "app_mymodel"."id", ... FROM "app_mymodel"`